# data.table way with .SDcols

Tags: r, format, data.table, na

I have a question for `data.table` using `.SDcols` to change.
Here is the example data:

```
dt
A   B   C   D
XX  XY  ""  ""
ZZ  ZA  ""  ""
```

What I want is using `.SDcols` to change `""` to `NA`.

I tried this:

```
dt[.SD == "", lapply(.SD, is.na), .SDcols = .(A, B, C, D)]
```

However, I got Error.

Any help? Appreciate.

Comment: should be just `dt[, (names(dt)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[x==""] <- NA; x})]`

Comment: Does `fread(..., na.strings=c("", "NA"))` get around your problem?

Comment: or if you must use `.SDcols`, then `dt[, (c("A","B","C","D")) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {x[x==""] <- NA; x}), .SDcols=c("A","B","C","D")]`

Comment: @ScottRitchie actually, the real data contains multiple columns that some need `"`.

Comment: @chinsoon12 add to answer and I'll mark it. Awesome.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Also `replace(x, x=="", NA)` or if there are no NAs to begin with maybe `is.na(x) <- x == ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the more robust method (which handle cases with no NAs) from Frank's comments, below are some timings for info.

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(6L)
N <- 1e7
numCols <- 100
pctEmpty <- 0.25
ltrs <- sample(LETTERS, N, replace=TRUE)
ltrs[sample(N, pctEmpty*N)] <- ""
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(ltrs, ncol=numCols))

str(dt)
dt1 <- copy(dt)
dt2 <- copy(dt)

microbenchmark(Replace=dt1[, (names(dt1)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x=="", NA_character_)), .SDcols=names(dt1)],
    Assign=dt2[, (names(dt2)) := lapply(.SD, function(x) { is.na(x) <- x == ""; x }) , .SDcols=names(dt2)],
    times=10L)

# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  Replace 234.0141 240.0262 311.2857 268.2718 401.9364 410.1788    10
#   Assign 273.1776 276.4123 344.1861 295.1337 435.8436 449.6495    10
```

The difference in timings is negligible. And of course, you can play around with the parameters to find the tradeoff depending on your needs.